# Activity Loads, but doesn't shows up

Tags: android, android-listview, android-actionbar

I have this code:

```
ListView listView;
static final String[] Liste = {"Satz des Pythagoras", "abc-Formel", "pq-Formel"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    setTitle("CalcPlus");
    listView = getListView();
    //Own row layout
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.activity_home, Liste));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_home, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.maths:
            return true;
        case R.id.physics:
            Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(Home.this, ActivityPhysics.class);
            startActivity(myIntent2);
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,
            int position, long id) {
    if ("Satz des Pythagoras".equals(Liste[position])) {
        Intent sdp = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(sdp, 0);
    }
    else if ("abc-Formel".equals(Liste[position])) {
        Intent abc = new Intent(view.getContext(), ActivityABC.class);
        startActivityForResult(abc, 0);
    }
    else if ("pq-Formel".equals(Liste[position])) {
        Intent pq = new Intent(view.getContext(), ActivityPQ.class);
        startActivityForResult(pq, 0);
    }
}
```

This should display a list and a actionbar.
It did, for some time.

It looks like I messed up the code and, since I'm not having that much experience, can't find my mistake...so could someone review my code? :)

Because now it loads the activity..but doesn't display the list or the actionbar :o

Here is the XML in \menu\activity_home.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never" />
<item android:id="@+id/maths"
    android:title="@string/maths"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText" 
    android:titleCondensed="@string/maths" 
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_calculator" /> 
<item android:id="@+id/physics"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_line_chart"
    android:title="@string/physics"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"/>
```

This is layout\activity_home.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So basically it's empty.

Comment: Are you getting error? Or simply those items aren't showing? How about log cat?

Comment: Did you try removing `listView = getListView();`?

Comment: Log Cat doesn't show any red entries.
Well, sometimes I get force close, I restart the program and it's working fine. I can't figure out, what's wrong..

Removing listView didn't change something :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these two lines:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
...
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.activity_home, Liste));
```

You are using the same layout for the entire Activity and each row, which doesn't make sense. The Activity's layout should contain a ListView and the row layout shouldn't...

---

To use the default layouts, remove this line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
```

and change this one:

```
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Liste));
```

---

**Also** you need to [`onListItemClick()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) not `onItemClick()` to have the row clicks work.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {...}
```

---

> Okay now the only entry in LogCat is Array Adapter:"You musst supply a resource ID for a textview.

You must give your TextView an id:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"/>
```

And change the way you create your adapter to:

```
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.activity_home, R.id.text, Liste));
```

Comment: I removed that other line, I get an error in line 27, which is:

listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
     R.layout.activity_home, Liste));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

Comment: Yes, you need the line `listView = getListView();` otherwise `listView` is `null`...

Comment: menu-xml has got a menu xmls and 3 items
layout-xml has got a relative layout xmlns and a textview.

Comment: That makes no sense to me. Click "edit" in the lower-left corner of your question to add the layouts.

Comment: Okay now the only entry in LogCat is Array Adapter:"You musst supply a resource ID for a textview.

Comment: To your edit: I now get an error with my public class Home extends ListActivity: The type Home must implement the inherited abstract method AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.onItemClick(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long)

Comment: Remove `implements OnItemClickListener` from your class definition and remove this line `listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);` they are redundant for a ListActivity.

Comment: Good. I still have the other error with "Resource ID for a textview" :(

Comment: Oh, yeah :) I'm still new to stackoverflow ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a ListActivity, your R.layout.activity_home has to have a ListView like:

```
     <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Then you can create a new layout for the list view item in your adapter or use a predefined layout for the list item like:

```
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Liste));
```

Comment: Can I also use my original activity_home? Because I don't want something else to show but the list (well and the actionbar).

Comment: @Lesik2008 Yes, if you are using activity_home for your list view item then you would remove the 'setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);' from the ListActivity as mentioned in Sam's post.